# count links based on placement and assign as variable? jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a id called mail_body, and in the mail_body is a bunch of random text and random links. By random I mean unknown called from a database, not truly random.

```
<div id="mail_body">
    Random unknown text with 

   <a href="...">
        a random
    </a> 

    amount of links 

    <a href="...">
        inside it
    </a>
</div>
```

I need a way to pass the link number as a variable to a new tracking link.

So the first link passes l=1 the second link pass l=2 the third l=3 and so on to the tracking link I have created.

```
$(document).on("click","#mail_body a", function() {
    var id = // code to figure out what number the link is
    event.preventDefault();
    window.open('trackinglink.php?l='+id, "_blank", '', false);
}
```

How can I figure out what the link number is relative to the placement of the div#mail_body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply get the counted `index` within the collection of all links

```
$(document).on("click", "#mail_body a", function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var $allLinks = $("#mail_body").find("a"); // collect
    var id = $allLinks.index( this );          // and find index

    window.open('trackinglink.php?l='+id, "_blank", '', false);
});
```

Comment: brilliant! ty ty ty :)

Comment: @Bruce y'w y'w y'w :)